# Better Spinner's listview run without click on it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I have simple problem with my fragment.. So i have a spinner and array string contain tow values.. On other hand and i have values on my firebase, I want set text from firebase not set. when i do that the problem  arises.. the spinner run without click on it and the array disappeared.

Note: i do that in activity and the problem does not occur and working 100%, i have this problem just in fragment.

```
// Array
String[] priv_secu_sec_values = new String[] {"All", "Friends"};

// Create adapter
final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
(getActivity(), 
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,priv_secu_sec_values);

// Create Spinner
final MaterialBetterSpinner edit_priv_secu = (MaterialBetterSpinner) 
v.findViewById(R.id.edit_sec_send);
edit_priv_secu.setAdapter(myAdapter);

// Get Value from firebase and set text
String priv_secu_send = 
dataSnapshot.child("rece_sec").getValue().toString();
edit_priv_secu.setText(priv_secu_send); 

// Spinner XML Code:
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
            android:id="@+id/edit_sec_send"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/Who"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

**My problem when is set text from firebase:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSwMQ.png)

**when i remove code set text from firebase and the problem does not occur**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl7z6.png)

**what i want..**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBFHi.jpg)

Comment: try `edit_priv_secu.setHint(priv_secu_send);` instead of `edit_priv_secu.setText(priv_secu_send);`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh ok i will try, but why the problem just in fragment so in activity workig 100%

Comment: I don't know(haven't used this lib) but technically you should use this and also verify the value of `priv_secu_send` using toast or logs and see if it is there